# How can i fix this error Mapper for [description] conflicts with existing mapper:Cannot update parameter [analyzer] from [my_analyzer] to [default]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

am new to elastic search.please help me out with this problem.

Am using elastic search version 7.13.2 .

I created an index with a custom analyzer and filter like this

```
PUT /analyzers_test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "english_stop":{
          "type":"standard",
          "stopwords":"_english_"
        },
        "my_analyzer":{
          "type":"custom",
          "tokenizer":"standard",
          "char_filter":["html_strip"
            ],
            "filter":[
              "lowercase",
              "trim",
              "my_stemmer"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer":{
          "type":"stemmer",
          "name":"english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then i created a mapping for the document i will have and specified my custom analyzer i created earlier (there is no document in the index yet)
like so:

```
PUT /analyzers_test/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "description":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "teaser":{
        "type": "text"
      
      }
    }
}
```

When i try try to create a document like so

```
POST /analyzers_test/1
{
  "description":"drinking",
  "teaser":"drinking"
}
```

i get the following error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapper for [description] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [analyzer] from [my_analyzer] to [default]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapper for [description] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [analyzer] from [my_analyzer] to [default]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) to add document to your index. You are missing the `_doc`

Comment: thats not the problem. if i leave out the part where i add the mapping,  the document is being added just fine but when i include the mapping and specify the custom analyzer  that error shows up.i want to be able to add that document with the mapping definitions that specify my custom analyzer

Comment: You explicitly add the mapping already, and then call `POST /index/id` which will create the mapping again (using default analyzer) and add the document. Hence, it throws conflicting error. If you do not add the mapping before then dynamic mapping will be automatically created for you and the document is also added in just one request. To add document to an index with explicit mapping, use the path `/index/_doc`

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. But it is the 'accepted answer', that is not fair.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Before my URL was http://localhost:9200/nameOfIndex/12345 and I was getting the same error. To get it to work, I changed it to http://localhost:9200/nameOfIndex/_doc/12345

Answer (score 1):

"You cannot change the mapping (including the analyzer) of an existing field. What you need to do if you want to change the mapping of existing documents is reindex those documents to another index with the updated mapping." [Abdon Pijpelink](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/change-analyzer-of-specific-property/99012/2)

Click the name for the original discussion